# Virus/Spyware: C2/Generic-B detected in C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Tags: virus, virus-removal, sophos

Sophos has detected the following:

**C2/Generic-B detected in C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe**

How do I get rid of this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: What happened when you ran a full Anti Virus scan?